# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: selenium

I am try to test the login function using selenium but I get this exception :

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='Guichet']"}
```

this my code :

```
public class LoginTest {

    public static WebDriver driver; 

    @BeforeClass
    public void testSetup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void openBrowser() {
        driver.get("http:url");
        System.out.println("We are currently on the following URL" +driver.getCurrentUrl());
    }

    @Test(description="This method validates the login functionality")
    public void loginFunction() {
        //WebDriverWait gui = new WebDriverWait(driver,100);

        //Locating the email field element via Name tag and storing it in the webelement
        WebElement guichet = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Guichet']"));
        WebElement matricule = driver.findElement(By.name("Matricule"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("Mot_de_passe"));
        WebElement save = driver.findElement(By.name("Valider"));
        //Entering text into the email field
        guichet.sendKeys("0000");

        matricule.sendKeys("login");
        password.sendKeys("password");
        save.click();

    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void postLogin(){
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.getCurrentUrl(), "http:url.html");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass(){
        //driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**NB :** I tried to use the and xpath but still does not work also I try to using some solution in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046783/org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-no-such-element) but no result

This the Html page Using the frame for menu and other form login pages

> SCT

:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META name="GENERATOR" content="">
<META http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<TITLE> 
</TITLE>
<LINK href="Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</HEAD>
<FRAMESET rows="14%,78%" frameborder="NO" border="0">
  <FRAME src="menu.html" scrolling="NO" name="entete">
  <FRAME src="SCT.html">
  <NOFRAMES>
  <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">
  <P>L'affichage de cette page requiert un navigateur prenant en charge les
  cadres.</P>
  </BODY>
  </NOFRAMES>
</FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Is it inside `iframe`? if it is you need to switch to it.

Comment: @Guy it's inside a table this is the pseudo html :  form > table > td > input

Comment: Provide DOM if possible

Comment: Have you tried to use visibilityOfElementLocated ?

Comment: @Guy I make a mistake it's inside a frame

Comment: Did you tried with driver.switchTo().frame(0); before performing driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Guichet']")) ?

Comment: @Medo : Please accept and upvote the answer if it resolved your problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
WebElement guichet = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Guichet']"));
WebElement matricule = driver.findElement(By.name("Matricule"));
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("Mot_de_passe"));
WebElement save = driver.findElement(By.name("Valider"));
//Entering text into the email field
guichet.sendKeys("0000");

matricule.sendKeys("login");
password.sendKeys("password");
save.click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```